# error in rsyslogd after upgrading to Debian9/Stretch Debian 8 without Jessie backports

Tags: debian, rsyslogd

After upgrading a Debian 8 without backports to Debian 9, when restarting `rsyslogd`, it trows the following error:

```
rsyslogd: the -4 command line option will go away soon.
Please use the global(net.ipprotocol="ipv4-only") configuration parameter instead.
rsyslogd: the -x command line option will go away soon.
Please use the global(net.enableDNS="off") configuration parameter instead.
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are due to rsyslog new versions changes.

In `/etc/default/rsyslog` I commented out the line:

```
#RSYSLOGD_OPTIONS="-4 -x"
```

Where x was there by default (I think), and -4 was an addition of mine.

I added in their substitution to `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
net.enableDNS="off"
net.ipprotocol="ipv4-only"
```

In Debian with the full backports this does not happens, as `rsyslogd` with this configuration was backported to Debian 8 a while ago.